# Why the Standard claims that containers are objects?

Tags: c++

Container's definition from the Standard:

> §23.2.1/1: **Containers are objects** that store other objects. They control allocation and deallocation of these objects through constructors, destructors, insert and erase operations.

I think the container's definition above contradicts with the definition from C++ Primer book (which I prefer):

> **Container is a type** whose objects hold a collection of objects of a given type.

It's obvious that (abstract) type can't be an object (any object must occupy a region of storage). 
You can say that C++ **container is a class template**. But templates are not objects too. There is a note about it from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object):

> The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function, enumerator, **type**, non-static class member, bit-field, **template**, class or function template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this.

So why the Standard claims that containers are objects? Maybe there is a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You prefer a textbook over the standard?

Comment: Its really the same thing.  They are saying `std::vector<int>` is a type and an instance of that type is an object, and that object holds other objects.  They standard just ignores the type part.

Comment: A severe misunderstanding on how the c++ standard influences the language.

Comment: Why is "Container" singular in the quote from the primer? It seems to me that we're missing some context from that quote. My understanding is that containers are objects are these objects' types are *container types*, and the quote is establishing the latter fact.

Comment: @NathanOliver I just hoped that the standard is a scrupulous thing and doesn't ignore parts of definitions.

Comment: @Rodvi: Why do you think that the standard ignores parts of definitions? You *do* realise that "C++ Primer book" is not the standard but some secondary literature, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to look at things so pedantically, then standard library containers are *neither* types nor objects. "Container" is a *concept*: a specific set of interfaces and behaviors which a type can conform to. `vector` is a template class which conforms to the concept of a sequence container.

There is no C++ type named "container". So unless there is some part of the book that you're not quoting, then the C++ Primer book is clearly wrong.

The standard is more technically correct. An object whose type conforms to a container concept is a container. Therefore, containers could be considered to be any object which conforms to the container concept.

Comment: Yes I missed part of the C++ Primer definition. This book also sais that "vector is a container type."

Comment: @Rodvi: Nicol's point is that a template isn't (itself) a type. `vector` isn't a type. `vector<int>` is one type, `vector<long>` is another type, `vector<char>` is yet another type, and so on. So no, `vector` isn't a container type, because `vector` isn't a type at all (but yes, this is getting pretty pedantic). The wording from the standard is accurate though. A container is an object. For example, if I define `std::vector<int> foo;`, then `foo` is an object which is a container.